# How do i convert a uint8_t to ascii?

Tags: assembly, x86

How do I convert an unsigned 8 bit integer to its ASCII representation in x86 assembly?  like in C:

```
uint8_t num=0xFF; 
char buf[4]={0}; 
sprintf(buf,"%u", num);
```

Now `buf` would now contain "255\x00" ; `num` happens to be in `byte ptr [eax+80]` and `buf` happens to be in `[004A1348]`  how would i do it in x86?

Comment: 16-bit or 32-bit x86 ?  Note that the code you show seems to assume that the result will be 3 chars in length, or the buf[4] line is redundant.

Comment: 32bit x86; oh, the 4th byte was just because sprintf adds a 0x00 at the end automatically, so sprintf needs 4 bytes buffer here :p

Answer (score 4):

There is no built in string formatting operator in x86 ASM. You have to write code to do that manually.

Without getting too deep into details, a string representation of the kind you're looking for calculates the the digits forming the base10 representation of the value ('2', '5', '5') and fills a memory range (buffer) with the values of the digits + a null terminator (0). One possible way to do that is by looping through the digits using division and modulo by 10 each step and to calculate the digit.

You can find examples of algorithms to do that online, for example [itoa](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implement-itoa/).

Comment: As Amit said: take `itoa()` as example. He or she gave a link. Just implement the C code in assembler.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis his initial answer only contained the first line :p the rest was added later.

Comment: @hanshenrik: Heheh. I didn't see that.